# Java Comparator throws Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

When I try to run this comparator for my entity system in Java:

```
private Comparator<Entity> spriteSorter = new Comparator<Entity>() {
    public int compare(Entity e0, Entity e1) {
        if (e1.position.getX() <= e0.position.getX())
            return +1;
        if (e1.position.getY() >= e0.position.getY())
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Here is the implementation:

```
private void sortAndRender(Bitmap b, Vec2 offset, ArrayList<Entity> l) {
    Collections.sort(l, spriteSorter);
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        l.get(i).render(b, offset);
    }
}
```

This issue only really began occurring when I was displaying large amounts of entities on the screen. What is going on here?

Comment: the greater than/less than signs are not correct, your comparison function is never returning zero

Comment: You didn't implement equals(Object) method.

Comment: @shuangwhywhy This has nothing to do with `equals`.

Comment: The contract referred to is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T%2C+T%29

Comment: @shuangwhywhy: equals is not compulsory. But still Comparator interface have equals method which ideally should be implemented. Even if we don' implement then it doesn't throw `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: Please don't correct your code in question by edits. You could invalidate the answers.

Comment: Please tick the correct answer instead of putting "SOLVED" in to the question title

Comment: voting to close since it looks like no answer will get accepted.

Comment: I cant tick my answer for another 2 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparator is just plain wrong.  Better would be something like

```
    if (e1.position.getX() != e0.position.getX())
        return Integer.compare(e1.position.getX(), e0.position.getX());
    if (e1.position.getY() != e0.position.getY())
        return Integer.compare(e1.position.getY(), e0.position.getY());
    return 0;
```

Comment: Your solution didnt work precisely, but I did notice what I had done wrong, so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

While @Louis beat me to it for the most part, to elaborate and possibly clarify...

Your Compare method must be fairly "stable" and complete.  Yours will return 0, "equals" for a lot of cases where the X and Y are different.

I'd rewrite it as

```
int result = Integer.compare(e1.position.getX(), e0.position.getX());
if (result == 0)
  result = Integer.compare(e1.position.getY(), e0.position.getY());
... if you have more to compare, add more if (result == 0) blah blah here...

return result;
```

As for "stable", let's say you have two points,  a = 4,2 and b = 2,4

When you compare a to b, you get 0
But when you compare b to a, you get 1.

This is "illegal" in a comparator.  a.compareTo(b) should equal -b.compareTo(a)

Answer (score 0):

Haha, issue was i was for some reason moving them up on the list based on x position, and down the list based on y position??!?!? This was a really silly mistake from me